# Self-dual vertex algebras

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quadratic-forms, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras

Let $(V,Y)$ be a self-dual conformal vertex algebra. For instance, it could be the vertex algebra associated to a positive definite, even, unimodular quadratic form. I look for a formula to compute
$$
Y(u,z)u^*,
$$
where $u\in V$ and $u^*$ is the corresponding element in $V^*$.

Comment: You are unlikely to find an explicit formula that fits the generality of your question.  Do you have some generators and their OPEs available?

Comment: Generators for $V$ ? You can assume that $V$ is lattice algebra